# Laravel navigate to next page of a HTML table with multiple pages (pagination)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, laravel

I have a customer.blade.php file containing HTML code basically a HTML `<table>` with header, body and footer. Now I have a JSON file containing customer data and I want to fetch the data from the json file and display it on the HTML table body. The table has 2 buttons

```
<button
    class="navigation-button"
    id="navigation-button--next"
    onclick="incrementPageCounter()"
> < </button>
Page: {{$pageCounter + 1}}
<button
    class="navigation-button"
    id="navigation-button--previous"
    onclick="decrementPageCounter()"
> > </button>
```

What I want is to display a partition of 20 rows on each page and when clicking the buttons, the table must display the partition of next or previous 20 rows.

```
@foreach(array_slice($partitionedCustomerTable[$pageCounter],0,20) as $customer)
```

Is there anyway to deal with `onclick` event of `<button>` tag using only PHP or I have to post a request from `<script>` tag>?

Here is my effort:

My PHP script:

```
$path = storage_path("app/public/data/json/customer_sample.json");
$jsonContent = file_get_contents($path);
$customerTable = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
$partitionedCustomerTable = array_chunk($customerTable,20,false);
$customerTableLength = count($partitionedCustomerTable);
$tablePageLimit = 20;
$pageCounter = 0;

var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST->action) && $_POST->action === 'next_page')
{
    $pageCounter++;
}
else if (isset($_POST->action) && $_POST->action === 'previous_page')
{
    $pageCounter--;
}
else
{
    echo("Error!");
}
```

My internal Javascript script:

```
function incrementPageCounter(pageNumber)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data:{ action: pageNumber + 1 },
        success: function(html)
        {
           alert(html);
           pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
        }
    });
}

function decrementPageCounter()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{view('customers')}}",
        data:{ action: 'previous_page' },
        success: function(html)
        {
           alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel, you can make in Controller: `$users=User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);`

In blade.php you can under table .... call `{{$users->links()}}` And you will need counter..